# Rewriting and Inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms

If $$2x/2^{y}\leq \epsilon$$ How is this inequality then achived when solving for y: $$f\geq \lceil\log_2{2x/\epsilon}\rceil=\lceil\log_2{1/\epsilon}+\log_2{2x}\rceil$$
I am confused about how $2x$ is moved over as the numerator for $\epsilon$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x > 0$,

$$\frac{2x}{2^f} \le \epsilon$$

Multiply by $2^f$,

$$2x \le \epsilon 2^f$$

Divide by $\epsilon$,
$$\frac{2x}{\epsilon } \le 2^f$$

$$2^f \ge \frac{2x}{\epsilon}$$

Now taking logarithm with base $2$,

$$f \ge \log_2 (2x) + \log_2 (1/\epsilon)$$

If there is additional information that $f$ is an integer, then we can take the ceiling function on the right hand side.

Comment: But how is it that $2x$ is moved over like that? I mean, above $\epsilon$. I seem to have forgotten how to solve inequalities..

Comment: i have added some explaination. hopefully it helps.

Comment: yes okay. that was simple enough. I overthought the the fact that it was an inequality. Thanks.

Comment: How is it that $\log_2{2b/\epsilon}$ is not $\log_2{2b}-\log_2{\epsilon}$?

Comment: $-\log_2 \epsilon = \log_2 (1/\epsilon)$. They are equal.